# Is there a way to monitor the signals an HID (Human Interface) device sends to the OS?

Tags: macos, mojave

There is a way in the mac world to monitor all the signals an HID device (a remote)  sends to the OS?
The final aim is to handle those and remap them to keyboard shortcuts.

More details: a Logitech remote I have (Logitech S510 media remote, a combo keyboard/mouse/remote) doesn't works on macOS (just the volume controls and few other buttons works). I was wondering if there is an easy way (in any language) to listen the remote signals and remap them. 
So the first step is to find a way to monitor the signals and check if all buttons signals are recognized by the OS.

Comment: Would this be considered a programming question and better elsewhere? Unsure here...

Comment: I’m not sure why the need to be vague with the question; “ a Logitech remote...doesn’t work on macOS.”  Which *specific* remote?  How does it (not) work with macOS? How do you know it’s an HID device if it doesn’t work with the OS?  There’s TONS of missing details here.

Comment: the remote is part of the kit Logitech S510. Some buttons of the remote works (volume controls, media buttons play/stop/pause) because they are standard signals. I want to use the other buttons.

Comment: The s510 is  *keyboard and Mouse combo*; nowhere on Logitech’s site do they have a “kit” that includes a remote.  Please post a photo showing the device and any model numbers so we can identify what you’re referring to

Comment: Just search for __Logitech S510 media remote__

Comment: Long chat with the OP. The S510 has several programmable buttons, but since the device is 10 years old, the vendor has EOL'ed macOS support. Their existing software is 32-bit and they aren't willing to create a 64-bit version for Mojave. OP planned to write a daemon to translate the buttons. Can't find the key code map online. Remote is a mouse with programmable buttons, and is USB HID.

Comment: @BillSmith all true, but the "remote" is an actual remote, not a mouse https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/414BTPGBVHL.jpg

Comment: You could try using the `keyboard` module in Python to monitor events - https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/.

Comment: I tried `keyboard`, I tried also `hid` https://pypi.org/project/hid/, I guess python is not a viable way (too much high level).. those modules handles just the classic keyboard keycodes..they doesn't even handle pretty common keys in several keyboards like "play/pause/stop"..even if the OS recognize that (it launches iTunes on press Play).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NSEvent

To monitor input events sent to macOS from Human Interface Devices (HID), look at NSEvent's [`addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1535472-addglobalmonitorforeventsmatchin?language=objc). This is the method used to associate scripts and tasks to hotkeys by third party macOS tools.

You will likely need to write in Objective-C or Swift and codesign the resulting binary. I expect you will also need to grant the binary additional access rights at runtime – probably in the **Accessibility** panel of **System Preferences > Security & Privacy**.

A [search on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask&type=Code) will provide a few sample projects using this method.

Comment: indeed this is a proper answer to the question. I know nothing about Swift, but I will take a look. I hope at OS API level there is a way to discriminate keyboard and remote by their device IDs or something. Thank you